# lateinit property mUserViewModel has not been initialized

Tags: android-studio, android-room, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I´m trying to read my database, therefore i have created an editext where I will enter a username and a button that allows me to search for the user,  but I am presenting an  the error in  class ListFragment : Fragment(), which says lateinit property mUserViewModel has not been initialized,please help me :(.

//Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int
)
```

//Dao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addUser(user: User)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table where firstName LIKE :search LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun readAllData(search : String) : User

}
```

//UserRepository

```
class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {
    suspend fun readAllData(user: String):User{
       return userDao.readAllData(user)
    }
}
```

//UserViewModel

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    
   private lateinit var repository:UserRepository
    
    fun search( search : String):User{
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.readAllData(search)
        }
  
        return search(String())
    }

}

}
```

//class

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {
    //erro(lateinit property mUserViewModel has not been initialized)
                lateinit var mUserViewModel:UserViewModel
                override fun onCreateView(
                    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
                ): View? {
                    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
            
                    val name = view.editTextTextNameee.text.toString()
                   val prueba = mUserViewModel.search(name)
            
                    if (prueba!=null){
            
                        textView1.text = prueba.firstName
                        textView2.text = prueba.lastName
                        textView3.text = prueba.age.toString()
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, " Unregistered use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
            
            
                    view.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
                    }
            
                    return view
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the lateinit not initialized property is you haven't created the ViewModel instance. can u try this

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment(), factory).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
```

// factory will be the instance of the View Model

you can observe the livedata changes the onviewCreated()

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because your Dao return a LiveData<List> so when you observe this data the return value is a List and not only a User. I don't know what you want to do. But you have to :

```
mUserViewModel.searchResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { 
             
              textViewName.text = it.name
              textViewLastName.text = it.lastname
              textViewAge.text = it.age
          })
```

And your query will be :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table where name LIKE :search LIMIT 1") 
suspend fun searchUser(search : String) : User
```

And in your mUserViewModel create a value searchResult and a method search:

```
fun search(val search : String){
viewModelScope.launch {
    searchResult.postValue(dao.searchUser(search))
}

}
```

Comment: Hi, I try to read my database, therefore I have created an editext where I will enter a username and a button that allows me to search for the user, but from what I see everything is wrong because it supports me with a video tutorial, I ask for your valuable help in correcting my database.

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo . May be I understood.

Comment: I have restructured my database, but I use the main thread, could you explain to me which is the best practice not to make use of this.

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo , it'll be too long. See this : https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0